# How do I vertical align cell content in a table in HTML?

Tags: html, css, html-table, vertical-alignment

i found the answers. but it doesn't work for me. please take a look at the code and tell me why user avatar is in the middle of the cell and not on the top

```
<http://jsfiddle.net/7nvku6zp/>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector is wrong

```
table.tablePost, tr.tablePost, td.tablePost {
  border: 1px solid black;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Means "apply the following to either a table, tr or td that all have the tablePost class". You don't have any td elements that have this class, only your table has it.

I can't really tell what you want your styles to look like but it might be this:

```
table.tablePost {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table.tablePost td {
  vertical-align: top
}
```

Which means "apply the border to any table elements with the tablePost class. Apply vertical-align to any td elements that are the children of any tables with the tablePost class."

Answer (score 0):

```css
td.description { vertical-align: top;}
```

```html
<td class="description">Description</td>
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.